# How to dynamically add point placement and point padding in fixed column chart (highcharts)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

when we add more data, how to set the point padding and placement dynamically 
This is the demo :
`http://jsfiddle.net/5vfojgsx/`

This is my question:

```
'http://jsfiddle.net/b135pxtw/'
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/b135pxtw/1/?

Comment: Hi Raeen, yes it works. What if the series has 15 data or 20 data. So, my question is how to dynamically change the point padding and placement according to the data series length. Thanks for your help...

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic? Does your data count change a lot?

Comment: Yes...If my data count is 10, the padding and placement should be applied based on the count and if i change to 20, then it should dynamically change the padding and placement values accordingly.

Comment: Do you mean the number of data in **`data: [203.6, 198.8, 208.5]`** or the number of series?

Comment: For clarification, data is the number of columns with the same color. Series are the different colored columns whose names are beneath the chart.

Comment: ok....i think i didnt explain my concept clearly. See..[link](http://jsfiddle.net/b135pxtw/) . here the series.length is 8 and you suggest me the answer. So, now the series.length is 12 and now you can change the padding and placement accordingly [link](http://jsfiddle.net/r8b97vuo/).  But each time, we cant change the padding and placement according to the length. So, we need a formula for the placement and padding which applies according to the series.length.  Hope, i explained my concept clearly. Thanks for your help

Comment: You are not yet telling what you want to do, but I can explain how it works. **`pointPlacement`**  is the distance from the center of every label (0,1,2). So positive means right, negative means left. Therefore when you have 10 series you should use spaces like (-0.4, -0.2, 0, 0.2, 0.4). For 12 you could use (-0.5, -0.3, -0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5). **`pointPadding`** is the width of every column so if you want two columns to overlap, you should use two values like (0.4, 0.45) as I used. This value should be less when using more data for the columns not to overlap with their neighbor like (0.45. 0.5)

Comment: Thank you. I understood the concept of point placement clearly but i have a small doubt in padding, beacuse if i give (0.5,0.6) its not working. So, how to plot the padding or is there any limitations in the padding ( like upto 0.5 only the padding will accept ).

Comment: No problem. Actually the padding is the space between each point (column). When you use smaller values, the space between them is smaller therefore the width could be bigger. So here in your case, you can interpret it as the reversed width of each column. As for the limitation, there isn't a limit.

Comment: I didnt get your concept for padding. Can you clearly explain it once again raeen

Comment: See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/nkhwLv1m/ **`pointPadding`** is 0.4 and 0.45. Now take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/nkhwLv1m/1/ **`pointPadding`** is 0.3 and 0.45. I only changed 0.4 to 0.3. As you can see, when I decreased the value, the width increased.

Comment: Really awesome raeen. I understood padding also. Thanks man.

Comment: You are so welcome. If it works let me post it as an answer then. Do you know how to accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me explain how it works.

**`pointPlacement`** is the distance from the center of every label `(0,1,2)`. So positive means right, negative means left. Therefore when you have 10 series you should use spaces like `(-0.4, -0.2, 0, 0.2, 0.4)`. For 12 you could use `(-0.5, -0.3, -0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5)`.

**`pointPadding`** is the width of every column so if you want two columns to overlap, you should use two values like `(0.4, 0.45)` as I [used](http://jsfiddle.net/b135pxtw/1/). This value should be less when using more data for the columns not to overlap with their neighbor, something like `(0.45. 0.5)`. You can see the difference [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nkhwLv1m/) and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nkhwLv1m/1/).

You can use these two options to dynamically place each column according to your data.